# ¿Cuál es la utilidad de las clases y métodos abstractos en php?

Tags: php, poo

Buenas, quería preguntar para qué se usan y qué ofrece el uso de las clases y métodos abstractos en php, también si recomiendan usarlas.

Comment: PHP tiene buena documentación en español donde puedes leer sobre [clases y métodos abstractos en PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.abstract.php). ¿Tienes alguna duda en particular? ¿Qué es lo que no entiendes?

Comment: Lo que no entiendo es cuál es la utilidad que tienen ellas

Comment: Ok. Como comentario, creo que la pregunta se podría hacer más genérica. Realmente la respuesta valdría para PHP o para cualquier otro lenguaje. Casi mejor usar [tag:lenguaje-agnóstico].

Comment: Pues sí, yo sé que hay varios lenguajes que también manejan las clases abstractas y demás, pero por ahora que me estoy centrando en php quisiera que fuera algo específico para él.

Comment: Es que no creo que haya nada de específico en una clase abstracta para PHP. Las propiedades/ventajas van a ser las mismas que para una clase abstracta en C# o en Java, por mencionar otros lenguajes.

Comment: Entonces podrías explicarme cuál es el uso que se les da en cualquier lenguaje.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con las clases abstractas, lo que se busca no es implementar la clase en sí (al menos no toda), sino crear un patrón/esqueleto de cómo debe estar estructurada la clase (parcial o totalmente). Como las clases abstractas no se pueden instanciar, su utilidad está relacionada con la herencia.

Una ventaja que tienen las clases abstractas es que pueden incluir la implementación de algunos métodos (a diferencia de las interfaces que sólo incluyen definiciones/firmas de los métodos pero no implementación), por lo que se podría ahorrar cierta repetición de código en las clases que heredan de la clase abstracta.

Por ejemplo, imagina que tienes una clase Polígono que sea para definir formas geométricas, y de la que heredarán otras clases como Cuadrado, Pentágono, Hexágono, etc. Tendrá propiedades y métodos definidos (p.e. una propiedad para el número de lados, y los métodos `get` y `set` para esa propiedad), aunque también habrá métodos que todas las formas geométrica tendrán pero que variarán de una a otra (p.e. un método que calcule el área), que por tanto no se pueden implementar en Polígono, pero que se debe imponer que se implementen en las clases que hereden. Esos métodos se definirán como métodos abstractos.

Comment: La parte de si recomendaría usarlas o no es subjetiva y va a depender del proyecto y lo que quieras hacer en particular. Por eso no incluí nada en la respuesta en sí.

Comment: Gracias, bastante claro.